# how to execute powershell command using ssh library robot framework in python

Tags: python, powershell, ssh

Am trying to execute powershell command on remote server using ssh library (robot framework).

code:

```
APP = "powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -Command "Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error -newest 3; [Environment]::Exit(1)"

stdout, stderr, rc = SSHConnection.execute_command(APP, return_stdout=True, return_stderr=True, return_rc=True)
print stdout, stderr, rc
```

problem is, if I don't use `[Environment]::Exit(1)` at the end of the powershell command, i don't see any output coming back. maybe this is due to shell again calling powershell issue. (i don't know)

If i don't use `[Environment]::Exit(1)`, then I get an error saying :

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `1\'\nsh: -c: line 0: `/bin/sh.exe -c "powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -Command "Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error -newest 3; [Environment]::Exit(1) "
```

Comment: is it the actual code? you have just opened a double quote and never closed it.

Comment: yes. should I add closing double-quotes at the end. like this :

APP = "powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -Command "Get-EventLog Application -EntryType Error -newest 3; [Environment]::Exit(1)""

Comment: first of all, it is a syntax error if you don't close opened quotes or double-quotes. Secondly, `stdout`, `stderr` and `rc` are stream objects which you should call their `readlines` (like: `stdout.readlines()`) in order to get the output of your executed command.

Comment: BTW, I saw nothing related to `Robot Framework` in provided codes; it is just pure python.